# how to find datevalue in 13 different sheets, import cells in column under date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

Parent Sheet holding data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vp_vMD4UzNvwpjaxjXmBh_se7hLW1S637cu95bjc4w8/edit?usp=sharing

The sheet I would like values imported to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Sqs6f5Rjf97jtlK7Cu_b2qn6cKT_S5oITmFQL_WYzo/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to search for `TODAY()` through 13 sheets, each sheet contains 4 weeks each.

I'd like to import the cells of the column following where `TODAY()` is found into a new worksheet.

Sheet names are `Week 45-48` `Week 49-52` etc.

[image]

Comment: @player0 updated with sheet links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(HLOOKUP(TODAY(), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1vp_vMD4UzNvwpjaxjXmBh_se7hLW1S637cu95bjc4w8", "Week 45-48!G148:G187"), 
 ROW(A1:A39), 0)))
```